# How to add urls in html widget in a gravity form?

Tags: widgets, urls, html, plugin-gravity-forms

I am using gravity forms for my website.

I added a html widget to add some text and urls to link to other pages of the site.

Code:

```
        <div name="comments" id="comments" 

        style="margin-bottom: 1em;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        width:100%;
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#000;">

        Listado de las politicas <a style="color:#C71585" href=”http://strippersjob.eu/es/politicas-de-privacidad/”>Politicas de Privacidad</a>, 
    <a style="color:#C71585" href=”http://strippersjob.eu/es/politicas-de-privacidad/”>Terminos y condiciones</a>, 
<a style="color:#C71585" 
         href=”http://strippersjob.eu/es/aviso-legal/”>Aviso Legal</a> y

  <a  style="color:#C71585" 
         href=”http://strippersjob.eu/proteccion-de-datos/”>Protección de Datos</a> , puedes dar click en cada uno, si quieres obtener más información.
</br>

  Si usted quiere cancelar su subscripción con nuestra agencia, por favor contactenos a través del link de <a style="color:#C71585"  href=”http://strippersjob.eu/es/politicas-de-privacidad/”>Contacto</a>  y su perfil será eliminado
        </div>
```

The issue is the domain url is overlap the url in href.  Instead of pointing to http:/strippersjob.eu/es/politicas-de-privacidad/    is pointing to http://strippersjob.eu/es/formulariostri/%E2%80%9Dhttp:/strippersjob.eu/es/politicas-de-privacidad/

Being http://strippersjob.eu/es/formulariostri/ the url of the form.

I need to avoid this ovelap.

How can i fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issues is with the Quotes your using in your html....

if what you have pasted is what you are actually using

```
  href=”http://strippersjob.eu/es/aviso-legal/”
```

These   href=**”**http://strippersjob.eu/es/aviso-legal/**”** quotes seem to be Typographic quotes and not acceptable html quotes.

The Typographic quotes are not really opening or clossing the href attribute so you are getting weird overlap and the browser is reinterpreting everything when you close the a tag later on.

you can see the **%E20** is an encoded quote at  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

So what you should do is retype all the quotes in your pasted code in your favorite text editor such as sublime text or phpstorm or even notepad. I think the root of your problem came from when pasted these URLS with the quotes around them from a word processor and that is what is causing all of your issues.